# What is the length of AR in the given triangle ABC?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I need your help with a question on triangles. It is from the entrance exam of an institute in India for students in 10th grade.

In the given triangle ABC, if 
**DP, MQ AR and ES are perpendiculars to BC such that DP = 6 cm, MQ = 4 cm and ES = 8 cm**
Then find AR.

[image: The image of the figure.]

**The image of the figure**

**The image of the original question with options** 
[image: The original question with options]

**MY ATTEMPT:** 
I tried to use Pythagoras theorem and tried substituting Pythagorean triplets to find the base.
Then I also tried similarity of triangles △DPC & △MQC and △ESB &△MQB to find the base BC.
I even tried to join AM and then extend it to intersect BC at F so as to use the Menelaus theorem and Ceva theorem. However, that didn't work for me too.

**Any help would mean a lot to me.**

Comment: Previous question: [Find the length of AR in the given triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4844706/89922)

Comment: Please provide me with some hints or the method to solve this tricky question. Your help would mean a lot to me.

Comment: It's a multiple choice question; consider a particular case where $B=P=R$ and $BQ = PQ = QS = SC$.

Comment: However @peterwhy it is not mentioned in the question that BQ=PQ=QS=SC. Even if it can be used ,it has to be proved so. If you know how to prove it, please share.

Comment: From the closers' reception of the previous question, I can only suggest (not answer) briefly. A way is to let the ratio $BQ:QC$, then express $BC$ in another way as $BR=RC$. Other users had different methods in the previous question.

Comment: I provided a hint of "Hint: Let $AM$ intersect $BC$ at $F$.  What is $FM / FA$? $\quad$ What have you tried in that regard? You mentioned Menelaus and Ceva's theorem, how have you applied them?

Comment: Yes @Calvin Lin I constructed the line FA and tried to find the ratios but I couldn't find anything useful to find the length AR. If you could provide me with a way to contact you I could send you the pic of my attempt because I can't share pics on comments.

Comment: You should be able to edit your question to show your working (and include pictures). $\quad$ None of us can add pics in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to solve using a combination of Euclidean Geometry and Analytic Geometry.  Let $Q = (0,0)$ and let $B = (x_1, 0), P=(x_2,0), S = (x_3, 0), C = (x_4, 0)$ then by similar triangles

$ \dfrac{x_4}{ x_4 - x_2 } = \dfrac{2}{3} \tag{1}$

$ \dfrac{ -x_1}{x_3 - x_1} = \dfrac{1}{2} \tag{2}$

Now, let vertex $A = (x, y)$ , then again by similar triangles,

$ \dfrac{x_4 - x_3 }{x_4 - x} = \dfrac{8}{y} \tag{3}$

$ \dfrac{x_2 - x_1}{x  - x_1} = \dfrac{6}{y} \tag{4}$

Taking the reciprocal of the last two equations, and re-arranging,

$ y = \dfrac{8 (x_4 - x)}{x_4 - x_3} = \dfrac{6(x - x_1)}{x_2 - x_1} \tag{5} $

Now looking back at the first two equations, we have

$ 3 x_4 = 2 x_4 - 2 x_2 \tag{6}$

So $x_4 = -2 x_2 \tag{7}$

And we also have

$ - 2 x_1 = x_3 - x_1\tag{8} $

So $ x_1 = - x_3 \tag{9}$

Substituting $(7)$ and $(9)$ into $(5)$, and writing $x_3 $ and $x_4$ in terms of $x_1 $ and $x_2$, gives us

$ y = \dfrac{ 8 (- 2 x_2 - x )}{- 2 x_2 + x_1} = \dfrac{ 6 (x - x_1)}{ x_2 - x_1} \tag{10}$

Solving for $x$ from the right most equation,

$$ 4 (-2 x_2 - x) (x_2 - x_1) = 3 (x - x_1) ( -2 x_2 + x_1) $$

Hence,

$$ x \left( 4 (x_1 - x_2) - 3 (-2 x_2 + x_1) \right) = 8 x_2 (x_2 - x_1) - 3 x_1 (-2 x_2 + x_1) $$

That is,

$$ x \left( x_1 + 2 x_2 \right) = 8 x_2^2 - 8 x_1 x_2 + 6 x_1 x_2 - 3 x_1^2 $$

$$ x \left( x_1 + 2 x_2 \right) = - 3 x_1^2 - 2 x_1 x_2 + 8 x_2^2 = (4x_2 - 3x_1) (2 x_2 + x_1)$$

Therefore,

$$ x = 4 x_2 - 3 x_1 $$

Substitute this in $(10)$

$$ y = 6\dfrac{ x - x_1}{x_2 - x_1} = 6 \left(\dfrac{ 4 (x_2 - x_1) }{x_2 - x_1} \right)= 24 $$

Therefore, $AR = 24$

Comment: Ouch (but I agree that anything works when we're desperate) $\quad$ There's a one-paragraph solution to this.

Comment: This is actually one paragraph.  But it is stretched.

Answer (score 2):

Like you thought, this is a question about similar triangles, so you should write down whatever ratios you know. You've implied a few of them already, and those are the important ones. You could be really close to a solution, but are just missing one important observation.
Unforuntately, this isn't a question about nice Pythagorean triples like you thought. Pythagorean theorem might be helpful, but it won't be my first choice.

The hint I gave was

> Let $AM$ intersect $BC$ at $F$. What is $\frac{ FM}{FA} $?

If we knew the answer to the hint, then using similar triangles, we can obtain $ \frac{FM}{FA} = \frac{ MQ}{AR} = \frac{4}{AR}$. So it remains to find $ \frac{ FM}{FA}$.

---

Recall the well-known fact

> $$\frac{FM}{FA} + \frac{ EM}{EB} + \frac{DM}{DC} = 1.$$

Hence, conclude that $ \frac{ FM}{FA} = \frac{1}{6} $ and so $AR = 24$.

Note

- The well-known fact can be proved using areas.
- Given that OP quoted Menelaus and Ceva's Theorem, I believe that they have seen this fact before.

Answer (score 1):

Menelaus's theorem with line $\stackrel{\longleftrightarrow}{CMD}$ and triangle $\stackrel{\triangle}{ABE}$:

$$\frac{AC}{CE}\frac{EM}{MB}
\frac{BD}{DA}=1$$
$$\frac{AR}{ES}\frac{ES-MQ}{MQ}
\frac{DP}{AR-DP}=1$$
$$\frac x8\frac{8-4}4\frac6{x-6}=1$$
$$\frac{3x}{4x-24}=1$$
$$x=24$$